# Can i run a Java application which needs a Selenium WebDriver on my Synology?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, synology

Does anybody have experience? I would like to run my Java app (spring boot app) on my Synology ds216j. The app needs a Selenium WebDriver for Chrome.

I actually do not know any way of instaling the web driver in synology..

Comment: The spring boot app will package all the dependencies(eg selenium webdriver, etc) it needs(including the tomcat server) into a jar file. I don't think you need anything to do in synology as far as the app.

Comment: No. You still need to install the webdriver separately even on your computer. Then in your app you provide an absolut address to this file: "/Users/XXX/chromedriver". Even if you can provide a path which is in your applications classpath (sth. like src/main/resources/chromedriver), when the selenium runs, it actually opens the chrome browser on your computer. How should the synology open a chrome browser at that moment? It does not have it..

Comment: @akcasoy Did you find anything to get this work?

Comment: @Nirostar unfortunately no.. maybe there is a solution now in 2019 but i don't know..

Comment: @akcasoy yeah I also gave up and I will run it on my Raspberry Pi instead...

Comment: Just as information.. actually you can also deploy a docker image in your NAS, and let run your selenium Tests headlessly in docker:  https://www.kenst.com/2018/09/how-to-run-your-selenium-tests-headlessly-in-docker/     But my 'small' synology (ds216j) does not support docker :/